# serialization check - compile time and runtime

Tags: java, serialization

i am looking for a tool, that can tell me whether a class / object is legal serializeable object (implements serializable, and all its fields are serializable).
i know that i can know whether an object is serializable only on run time.
i want to get warning on compile time, whether a class can be not serializable (e.g - a member is not serializeable, although in runtime it can be null, or of seriazliable sub class type). in addition, on runtime i want to check if a class is really serializable, before trying to send it over the network as a serialized object.

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done using static code analysis.

One tool that's used a lot is [Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/).  It will tell you about many common problems and suspect behaviour.  One of its checks is the one you mention [(described here)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SE_BAD_FIELD).

There are plugins for most IDEs for this, so it can do its job while you work, and a common pattern is to include this in your automatic build.

Answer (score 4):

Does it have to be compile time? I've done this with unit tests before, which is pretty close to compile time in terms of development lifecycle. [This article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-serialtest/index.html) is a bit dated but outlines a few good approaches. We also caught unserializable state by doing a true failover test for our webapp using two web servers, which is why I needed to verify serializability.

Comment: you forgot to attach link to "this article"

Comment: @AlexR - I fixed it about 15 seconds after posting, you're fast!